# Impossible to find or load the main class (good classpath, good manifest, good class)

Tags: java, jar, execution

Here is the error I encounter : "**Impossible to find or load the main class MCP**".

**My project is structured like this :**

```
- src (directory containing the sub-directory (and package) "tp2" containing the source files (their package is "tp2")).
- class (directory containing the directory (and package) "tp2" containing the class files)
- META-INF (directory containing "MANIFEST.MF" (only one line : "Main-Class: tp2.MCP")).
```

1. I'm building my project with `javac src/tp2/*.java -d class`.
2. I create my ".jar" with `jar cfmv MCP.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF class/tp2/`
3. **I want to tell you that I've added `./class` in my `CLASSPATH`.**

However, the error is still there... And when I do `jar -tf MCP.jar`, I have :

```
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
class/tp2/XXYYZZ.class
class/tp2/MCP.class
```

**It seems the classpath isn't correctly read at the execution ?**

Answer (score 0):

Your jar file is including the `class` directory. Therefore it's treated as part of the package name.

Use the `-C` flag when creating your jar

```
java cfmv MCP.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF -C class .
```

From `man jar`:

> -C dir         Temporarily changes directories to dir while processing the following inputfiles argument.  Multiple -C dir inputfiles sets are allowed

Comment: And what if I wrote "class.tp2." in the MANIFEST ?

Comment: It seems clear from your `javac` command that your package name is `tp2`, not `class.tp2`.

Comment: Yes but if I write "class.tp2" in the files' first line "package class.tp2;" and I I write "class.tp2" too in the manifest ? Would it avoid me from using the -C ?

Comment: Yes, to create another directory "class" into the source one, but technically, even if it's really stupid, it would work ?

Comment: There's one way to find out: try it.